# Expected value in a Poisson process

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, expected-value, poisson-distribution

The problem is from [this](https://youtu.be/MvGuBQZZuLM?t=804) lecture video. Fish are caught in a Poisson process with parameter $\lambda$. You fish for 2 hours, if in that time you catch at least one fish, then you stop at 2 hours time. Otherwise, you continue to fish until you catch one fish. The question is, what is the expected number of fish $E[N]$. Where $N$ is the random variable for the number of fish.

In the lecture, the professor states that the answer is simply:
$$E[N]=\lambda\tau + P_P(0,2)(1)$$

Here, $P_P$ is the probability distribution for the number of arrivals $k$ in some interval $\tau$:
$$P_P(k, \tau) = \frac{(\lambda\tau)^ke^{-\lambda\tau}}{k!}$$

I don't get why the first term does not have a factor of $1-P_P(0,2)$ which is based on the total expectation theorem:
$$E[N]=P(F)E[N|F] + P(F^c)E[N|F^c]$$

Here, let $F$ be the event that you fish for 2 hours and thus $F^c$ will be the event that you fish for more than 2 hours since you have not caught any fish in the first 2 hours.

Comment: Oh sorry, $F$ should be that you fish for only 2 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather unfortunately, the notation that is used is not ideal.  A better way to conceptualize the problem is to write the model as follows.  As stated in the lecture, let $N_\tau$ be the number of fish caught in $\tau$ hours, if you were to simply fish for that amount of time, irrespective of the number of fish caught.  Then $$N_\tau \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda \tau).$$  Now let $S$ be the random number of fish caught under the conditions of the problem, in which if $N_2 = 0$, then you continue to fish until one more is caught.  The reason I use a different variable here is because $S$ is not Poisson and there is no definite stopping time specified; thus I do not want to use the name $N$ as I don't want to confuse it with $N_\tau$.  Now we can write $$S = \begin{cases}N_2, & N_2 \ge 1 \\ 1, & N_2 = 0. \end{cases}$$  So $$\operatorname{E}[S] = \operatorname{E}[N_2 \mid N_2 \ge 1]\Pr[N_2 \ge 1] + \operatorname{E}[1 \mid N_2 = 0]\Pr[N_2 = 0].$$  I think this is what you had in mind when applying the law of total expectation.  Rather than introducing a new event $F$, one can simply use the existing notation $N_2 \ge 1$ to represent the event that one fishes for only $2$ hours.  All that is left is to execute the calculation:

$$\Pr[N_2 \ge 1] = 1 - e^{-2\lambda}, \\ \operatorname{E}[N_2 \mid N_2 \ge 1] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n \frac{e^{-2 \lambda}}{1 - e^{-2 \lambda}} \frac{(2 \lambda)^n}{n!} = \frac{2\lambda}{1-e^{-2\lambda}},$$ hence $$\operatorname{E}[S] = 2\lambda + e^{-2\lambda}$$ as claimed.  But why does this simplify so nicely?  Well, let's look at it another way now.  We write $$S = N_2 + \mathbb 1(N_2 = 0),$$ where $\mathbb 1$ is the indicator function that equals $1$ if $N_2 = 0$ and $0$ otherwise.  Equivalently, $\mathbb 1(N_2 = 0)$ is a Bernoulli random variable in which the parameter $p = \Pr[N_2 = 0]$.  Then by linearity of expectation, $$\operatorname{E}[S] = \operatorname{E}[N_2] + \operatorname{E}[\mathbb 1(N_2 = 0)] = 2\lambda + \Pr[N_2 = 0] = 2\lambda + e^{-2\lambda}.$$  This is what the solution in the lecture did.  Note we did not use the law of total expectation--we did not condition on the outcome of $N_2$--but we did use the linearity of expectation.  The reason this works is because we reframed the model for $S$ in a way that is not directly conditioned on $N_2$.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed solution! Do you think you can explain a bit more on how you got the term $\operatorname{E}[N_2 \mid N_2 \ge 1] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty x \frac{e^{-2 \lambda}}{1 - e^{-2 \lambda}} \frac{(2 \lambda)^n}{n!}$? How come you divide by $1-e^{-2\lambda}$ in the sum?

Comment: @ZoomBee The PMF of the conditional random variable $M = (N_2 \mid N_2 \ge 1)$ is a zero-truncated Poisson, namely $$\Pr[M = m] = \frac{\Pr[(N_2 = m) \cap (N_2 \ge 1)]}{\Pr[N_2 \ge 1]} = \frac{e^{-2\lambda} \lambda^m/m!}{1 - e^{-2\lambda}}$$ where we have applied the definition of conditional probability, $\Pr[A \mid B] = \Pr[A \cap B]/\Pr[B]$.

Comment: I suppose for this PMF to be valid, $m \geq 1$?

Comment: @ZoomBee Correct.  Since $N_2$ has support on $\{0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots, \}$, it follows that $M$ has support on the positive integers $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots \}$.

Answer (score 1):

You always fish for the first two hours.  The expected number of fish caught in this time is $2\lambda$.  Your only fish for the period after two hours if you have caught no fish in the first two hours, and the lecturer represents the probability of this event as $P_P(0,2)$.  The total expectation is $$2\lambda +P_P(0,2)\cdot1$$  (We have $\tau=2$.)  There is no factor of $P(F)$ on the first term, because you *always* fish for the first two hours.